# Ubuntu 14.04 installer does not detect Windows on drive, missing "Install alongside" option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

Firstly some information about my computer. I just have a C: drive and a D: drive. My C: drive just has a bunch of programs and my D: drive has all my work.

I am running windows 7 and I'm trying to also have Ubuntu on my desktop too.

1. I burned a ubuntu14.04.1.iso file onto a DVD.
2. Then I rebooted my desktop and changed my boot options to boot from the DVD.
3. It loaded ubuntu and asked me to pick my language etc etc but then these dialogs came up and I didn't know what to choose...

[image]

I didn't want to pick the first option because I was scared it might delete my windows or something so I clicked on **Something else** and got this window.

[image]

Now from this window I had no idea what was going on so I just quit the installation, took the DVD out and went back to windows. How am I supposed to proceed?

I remember seeing a post that said I should get an option like this, which allows me to install ubuntu with windows 7 but I never got it.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is now kinda tricky because your windows installation was not recognized correctly. Make sure you fully shut windows down before installing Ubuntu (no Hybernate mode etc. (!)). You could start from the DVD again and run the live session and try installing Ubuntu from there.

The only problem I see is that you don't have any left over (empty) harddrive or partition so you can't install Ubuntu into it's own space.

Another option is installing Ubuntu on a (fast!) USB stick or switch completely which means backing up all your files and then click on

> `Erase disk and install Ubuntu`

Comment: Should it be installed on my C: drive or D: drive preferably

Comment: Are those two different drives? If yes, install it on the drive where your system is stored (C: drive) because potential data loss is way smaller if all your data is stored on D:. If those are just two prtitions on one single (physical) harddrive then there is no difference in case of faults or data loss.

Comment: Okay this is very confusing... How about the USB option, how does that work. I'm guessing that the ubuntu takes up no space on my computer and everytime I want to go into ubuntu I need to plug in my usb?

Comment: Correct! But if you install Ubunutu on a stick (including Grub2 (the bootloader)) you need to have your USB stick plugged in all the time to have the bootloader load.

Comment: Have you tried the other suggestions?

Comment: Well I tried installing it on C: but it wants to erase the disk THEN install it. Eventhough my C: drive has 200gb+ of free space and ubuntu only needs 5gb or something

Comment: Have you tried installing it from the live session? Don't forget to fully shut down windows. Elseways Ubuntu could not mount your windows drives correctly.

Comment: Oh you mean run the demo version, then double click on the LTS file thing that's on the desktop? I'll try that but I don't see why it would change anything.

Comment: It might make a difference because you could click on your harddrive in the sidebar and see if Ubuntu has full access to it. If yes, try installing by clicking the icon, if no than there is some problem with windows that needs further investigation.

Comment: I'm currently in the demo ubuntu now. The problem persists. I don't have authorization to access any of the drives either.

Comment: So the problem is found. Your windows does something with your harddrives upon shutdown. Can you give some information abour your windows installation and how you shut it down?

Comment: All I know is that it's windows 7. And I just click start > shut down. Then I wait for it to turn off. Then I turn it back on. What do you think about the answer below. User adjustingthesound says that i should shrink my drive. In the link that the other user provided, it says **Windows takes up the whole of the drive when it is first installed. In order to install Ubuntu you will need to make space for it.**. So do you think I should try shrinking my C: drive?

Comment: I would say it's a possibility but I don't like shrinking hdd's because it takes really long and risk of data loss is very high. When installing Ubuntu in windows (the option you are missing) it will automatically shrink your windows partition so no need to manually do it. What I suggest you is looking up how to disable hybernate mode in windows 7 and then try again installing Ubuntu. The problem with windows is always the same (beeing unable to open it's NTFS partitions).

Comment: My current power plan options says to never hibernate.

Comment: Sorry I meant to deactivate the `suspend` (to HDD) mode. I didn't use windows in over two years now and my origin is Germany so I primarily know the German words for those modes..

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/turn-off-hibernatesuspend/fbaf54c3-b391-4cd8-8188-6a529347c101 The second answer is what you have to do. In windows 7 open CMD with administrator rights and type `powercfg -h off`. Then shutdown and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16031/discussion-between-flatron-and-ogen).

Answer (score 0):

You could shrink some space on your hard drive used by **C:** or **D:**

In Windows press **WinKey+R**, input `diskmgmt.msc`, press **Enter**. It will open **Disk Management** where you can right-click on **C:** or **D:** and choose **Shrink volume**. You will see a window where you can specify space to shrink.

It will give you an unallocated area, which you can format in ubuntu installation and use for Ubuntu. It will not make you erase anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide for Windows 8.1 but I found it very helpful. I think it will work for Windows 7 + Ubuntu dualboot. Since your main problem seems to be the partitions, check it out:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html